# mediaprojection : Black screen in some cases

Tags: android, android-mediaprojection

Using "mediaprojection" I was able to capture the current screen from a background service.
The sdk api is 25, Android 7.1.2, and I checked it with an emulator running with BlueStacks without rooting and my mobile phone without rooting.
But when I test it with BlueStacks and another emulator, Nox, I get a black screen.
The same code and only in the Knox emulator without rooting the same code is black screened in the result.

Could the results be different depending on the emulator?
Do you have a "mediaprojection" application running in a background service to test this case?

Comment: Some emulators work and some don't.

Comment: Install an app that records the current screen and check whether the current emulator is recording or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem before but I noticed that bluestacks doesn't allow the use of applications with mediaprojection you can't try in your own device if you want to test apps that can take screenshots or similar situations